# Redirect/Hide certain HTML is user is on a mobile device?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been working on my website and putting finishing touches on it so I can have it to show employers when I start job hunting since I graduate soon. I built an "about" section that uses parallax scrolling...issue is, it just does not work in any capacity on mobile devices. At least not well. Here is what I am referring to: http://www.jordanmorgan.net/about.html

What I would like to do is, just scrap that all together if they are on a device that's less than 900px in width, or whatever amount. I would rather just display a traditional about me page. So how could I write up some javascript do determine what device they are using, and display different HTML or go to a different page all together if needed if they are on said device.

Any advice would be great on how to best solve the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've actually been looking into this myself today, and I've come up with the following function...

```
function isMobile() {
    return (typeof window.orientation !== 'undefined');
}
```

That determines whether a device is mobile or not by whether the orientation can change (doesn't happen on a desktop device).

This is preferable, for me, as it means I don't have to worry about user agent values being changed on some devices, and I don't have to go back and add new browsers as they come out.

Also, many handheld devices now have very high screen resolution, so you can't rely on screen size either.

Answer (score 2):

You could use JavaScript to refer the visitor to another URL.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

            if( navigator.userAgent.match(/(android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile)/i) )
            {
            document.location.replace("/mobile/");
            }

    </script>
```

You could also make a [responsive web design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)

which would be the best solution for both your user and the SEO.

Comment: @estrat It is built on bootstrap, so it is pretty responsive...a few issues here and there. Only issue is I would like to be able to span more columns if the view isn't on a desktop...my site looks cramped on an iPad. I might use your code to help fix that. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

```
mobileDeviceCheck: function(system) {
    if(system) {
        if(navigator.userAgent.match(system)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        };
    } else {
        if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i))) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        };
    };
}
```

Uniwersal function